# Angular 2 Fetch data between two components

Tags: angular, product, detailsview

we have two pages 1) product and 2) product detail page

1. page 1 has product cart which is shown in the image. There you can see the product details.
2. page 2 we have product detail page in which product image,price,size,color,etc will be shown. when a customer clicks those fields and click on add to cart details should show in the first page in add to cart details.

product detail page

[image]

product page

[image]

Comment: What's the relationship between these components? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Kindly ask us a question.

Comment: Basically i want to share interger value between two componets. and i have tried event emitter

Comment: @abhinavromeo : Did my answer help you solve your issue ?

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to notify one component about the other component, you can create a Subject that can notify  other subscribers. [Take a look at this code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thlr64?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Create a service file which will be common for both components

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class CommonSvc{

  public mySub = new Subject<number>();
  public counter: number = 0;

  increaseCounter(){
    this.counter++;
    this.mySub.next(this.counter);
  }

}
```